# combine results from sql query and javascript to calculate a field

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql

I am very new to JavaScript, 
Have a problem regarding arrays within javascript.
Straight to the point:
I have HTML code:

```
<input type="text" name="conPrice" id="conPrice" size="16" maxlength="128"/>
<input type="text" name="OverP" id="OverP" size="16" maxlength="128"  />
<div id="slider"></div> //Slider
```

First field for quantity, that is pulled from slider.
Second field for price from SQL table

SQL is based on a condition that there is four fields:

```
| ID | MIN | MAX | PRICE |
```

I am trying to get a price column prices in field **OverP** depending on what my sliders value is. so, if for example I have number 6 on a slider and it is between 1-7 as MIN and MAX, so the price would be 10.

I have this SQL:

```
<?php
$x = mysql_query("SELECT p_max AS max FROM dsd_price");
$y = mysql_query("SELECT p_min AS min FROM dsd_price");
$z = mysql_query("SELECT p_price AS price FROM dsd_price");
while ($x_array = mysql_fetch_array($x)){$max[] = $x_array;}
while ($y_array = mysql_fetch_array($y)){$min[] = $y_array;}
while ($z_array = mysql_fetch_array($z)){$price[] = $z_array;}
?>
```

And finally my JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function slider() {
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    value:1,
    min: 0,
    max: 201,
    step: 1,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
//Its setting the slider value to the element with id "conPrice" 
$("#conPrice" ).val(ui.value);
    }
});
});

$(document).ready(function calcul() {
var frm = document.dsd_form;
var quant = frm.conPrice;
var overp = ['<?php echo implode("','", $price); ?>'];
var mini = ['<?php echo implode("','", $min); ?>'];
var maxi = ['<?php echo implode("','", $max); ?>'];
for(index = 0; quant > mini[index], quant < maxi[index]; index++){
    $( "#OverP" ).val( overp[index] );
})
}   
</script>
```

I am not getting a result I wish, I know that the problem is with my JS.
Hope for some suggestions to my topic as soon as possible.

UPDATE:
Putting in whole code of the test page so far. slider does slide, the slider value is being processed to conPrice, but calculation does not work...

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<!-- For slider -->
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- Slider JS -->
<?php
$x = mysql_query("SELECT p_max AS max FROM dsd_price");
$y = mysql_query("SELECT p_min AS min FROM dsd_price");
$z = mysql_query("SELECT p_price AS price FROM dsd_price");
while ($x_array = mysql_fetch_array($x)){$max[] = $x_array['max'];}
while ($y_array = mysql_fetch_array($y)){$min[] = $y_array['min'];}
while ($z_array = mysql_fetch_array($z)){$price[] = $z_array['price'];}
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function slider() {
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    value:1,
    min: 0,
    max: 201,
    step: 1,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
  //Its setting the slider value to the element with id "conPrice" 
  $("#conPrice" ).val(ui.value);
    }
 });
    function price(){
    var frm = document.dsd_form;
    var quant = frm.conPrice;
    var overp = ['<?php echo implode("','", $price); ?>'];
    var mini = ['<?php echo implode("','", $min); ?>'];
    var maxi = ['<?php echo implode("','", $max); ?>'];
    for(var index = 0; quant > mini[index], quant < maxi[index]; index++){
        $( "#OverP" ).val( overp[index] );
    }
}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="dsd_form" name="dsd_form" action="db_create_sql.php" method="post" class="niceform">
<fieldset>
       <dl>
            <dt><label for="conPrice">Price:</label></dt>
            <dd><input type="text" name="conPrice" id="conPrice" size="16" maxlength="128" />
            <input type="text" name="OverP" id="OverP" size="16" maxlength="128" />
            <div id="slider" ></div>
            </dd>
        </dl>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Having SQL database:

```
p_id | p_min | p_max | p_price
  1        1      1       11
  2        2      5       13
```

Comment: So far I am not getting any, because there must be an error in a last part of JS. If I would take out the part starting with $(document).ready(function calcul() {
it is giving me slider and number output to conPrice

Comment: Try using a browser tool such as Firebug (Firefox) or Chrome's dev tool (F12 to open it). It would show any JS errors

Comment: hi, no luck, tried to look for error in FireFox, doesn't show me any that might be related to the topic

Comment: Try Chrome's dev tool then. If nothing pops up in red, then you at least don't have JS syntax errors. Also, your Javascript looks like jquery. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, it is, and I am calling for <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> so that should not be an issue

Comment: The point is that at the moment slider is working fine. It does send a value to #conPrice field, but #OverP field doesn't want to calculate

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your brackets don't match up for the calcul() function. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function calcul() {
var frm = document.dsd_form;
var quant = frm.conPrice;
var overp = ['<?php echo implode("','", $price); ?>'];
var mini = ['<?php echo implode("','", $min); ?>'];
var maxi = ['<?php echo implode("','", $max); ?>'];
for(index = 0; quant > mini[index], quant < maxi[index]; index++)
{
    $( "#OverP" ).val( overp[index] );
}});
```